# Догрузка постов на WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, ajax

Как реализовать кнопку догрузки постов на WordPress?
Пробовал действовать по инструкции Миши Рудастых, но есть ряд проблем:

1. Догружаются все посты, а мне нужно столько сколько установлено в Админ панели
2. Вместе в Респонсом постов догружается символ "0"
3. Если не закаментить die() этот скрипт вообще не работает

что в моем коде не правильно?

**Страница блога**

```
<div class="posts">
                    <?php
                    $current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // определяем текущую страницу блога
                    $args = array(
                        'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'), // значение по умолчанию берётся из настроек, но вы можете использовать и собственное
                        'paged'       => $current_page // текущая страница
                    );
                    query_posts( $args );

                    $wp_query->is_archive = true;
                    $wp_query->is_home = false;

                    while(have_posts()): the_post();
                        ?>
                        <!-- Post -->
                        <a class="item" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <h3 class="text-uppercase"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            <p>Posted by <?php the_author(); ?> on <time datetime="<?php the_date('Y-m-d'); ?> <?php the_time( $d ); ?>" title="Date of publication"><?php echo get_the_date('j F, Y'); ?></time></p>
                        </a>
                        <!-- / Post -->
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                    
                    <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
                        <script>
                            var ajaxurl = '<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
                            var true_posts = '<?php echo serialize($wp_query->query_vars); ?>';
                            var current_page = <?php echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>;
                            var max_pages = '<?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>';
                        </script>
                        <button id="true_loadmore" class="btn btn-normal btn-orange btn-material"><span class="btn-material-effect js-ripple"><i class="btn-material__circle"></i></span><span class="btn-name">Older Posts</span></button>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </div>
```

**loadmore.js**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#true_loadmore').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.btn-name').html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span><span>Loading...</span>'); // изменяем текст кнопки, вы также можете добавить прелоадер
        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': true_posts,
            'page' : current_page
        };
        $.ajax({
            url:ajaxurl, // обработчик
            data:data, // данные
            type:'POST', // тип запроса
            success:function(data){
                if( data ) {
                    $('#true_loadmore').text('Загрузить ещё').before(data); // вставляем новые посты
                    current_page++; // увеличиваем номер страницы на единицу
                    if (current_page == max_pages) $("#true_loadmore").remove(); // если последняя страница, удаляем кнопку
                } else {
                    $('#true_loadmore').remove(); // если мы дошли до последней страницы постов, скроем кнопку
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**functions.php**

```
function true_loadmore_scripts() {
    // wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // скорее всего он уже будет подключен, это на всякий случай
    wp_enqueue_script( 'true_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/loadmore.js', array('jquery'), time() );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'true_loadmore_scripts' );

function true_load_posts(){

    $args = unserialize( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ) );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // следующая страница
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

    // обычно лучше использовать WP_Query, но не здесь
    query_posts( $args );
    // если посты есть
    if( have_posts() ) :

        // запускаем цикл
        while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
            <!-- Post -->
            <a class="item" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <h3 class="text-uppercase"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <p>Posted by <?php the_author(); ?> on <time datetime="<?php the_date('Y-m-d'); ?> <?php the_time( $d ); ?>" title="Date of publication"><?php echo get_the_date('j F, Y'); ?></time></p>
            </a>
            <!-- / Post -->
        <?php
    endwhile;

    endif;
// die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'true_load_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'true_load_posts');
```

Comment: Заметка на полях. Опять Рудрастых даёт вредные советы. query_posts - для ядра, и о её использовании надо просто забыть. Проблема здесь не в этой функции, но сам подход...

Comment: 'обычно лучше использовать WP_Query, но не здесь' - просто идиотский камент

Comment: Что посоветуете использовать для такого случая?

Comment: WP_Query или get_posts() - для любого случая везде, кроме отдельного участка ядра.

Comment: Читайте Каму, а не Рудрастых: https://wp-kama.ru/note/opasno-ispolzovat-query_posts

Comment: Так в целом код правильный, нечему там не работать. То, что die надо комментировать - следствие каких-то проблем вовне этого кода. Отключите все плагины, смените тему на стандартную, перенесети в неё вот этот loadmore, и вы увидите, что всё работает.

Comment: Прочитал ту статью которую вы прикрепили, там все проще, единственное не понял как сделать `posts_per_page` выводимым из админки, просто мне нужно чтобы не я указывал 'posts_per_page' => 2, а администратор

Comment: Переменная $d не определена. Это может вызывать вывод ошибки на экран и портить вывод.

Comment: posts_per_page=0 заставит использовать этот параметр изх админки.

Comment: В коде 'posts_per_page' => 0, в админке установлено 2, но выводит все посты

Comment: Переписал на 'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'), теперь работает

Comment: Вот код ядра, который делает ровно то же самое. Когда 0, используется число из админки: https://prnt.sc/z76jrl

Comment: <?php $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),);$lastposts = get_posts( $args );foreach( $lastposts as $post ){setup_postdata( $post );?><!-- Post --> <a class="item" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3 class="text-uppercase"><?php the_title(); ?></h3> <?php the_excerpt(); ?><p>Posted by <?php the_author(); ?> on <time datetime="<?php the_date('Y-m-d'); ?> <?php the_time( $d ); ?>" title="Date of publication"><?php echo get_the_date('j F, Y'); ?></time></p></a><!-- / Post --><?php } ?>

Comment: Так это потому,, что используете get_posts. Там свои предустановки до вызова WP_Query. С ним надо ставить numberposts в ноль. См. код get_posts.

Comment: Но мы далеко ушли от темы. Работает код теперь?

Comment: Теперь все работает, можете постить ответ!

Comment: И что, die не закомментировано теперь?

Comment: Я полностью передал обработчик и js благодаря той статье которую вы прикрепили

Comment: Ну это не тянет на ответ. Комментарий.

Comment: В любом случае вы мне помогли, спсибо вам огромное!